# rust question: temporary value dropped while borrowed

Tags: rust

i have code below,

```
    enum List<'a> {
        Cons(i32, Box<&'a List<'a>>),
        Nil,
    };
    let list= Cons(10, Box::new(&Nil));
    let lista = Cons(5, Box::new(&Cons(10, Box::new(&Nil))));
    match lista {
        Cons(x,_) => println!("{}",x),
        Nil => ()
    }
```

after running the code, the compiler says

```
21 |     let lista = Cons(5, Box::new(&Cons(10, Box::new(&Nil))));
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement 
   |                                   |
   |                                   creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
```

i can understand 'Cons(10, Box::new(&Nil))' is freed, so it goes wrong. but when i replace list with lista after match, eg:

```
    match list {
        Cons(x,_) => println!("{}",x),
        Nil => ()
    }
```

i think Nil is also a temporary value and dropped at the end of statement, but it runs well,  what's the difference between list and lista?

Comment: I think `Box<&…>` is generally meaningless. Use `Box<List>` (or `&'a List<'a>` if you want [on-stack](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/infinity-stack-allocated.html) or bump-allocated lists.) In any case, have a look at the [Too Many Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/index.html) book, if that's not what you're doing already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of [rvaue static promotion](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1414-rvalue_static_promotion.html). Enum variants with all const values are constexpr, and therefore are promoted to a `'static` lifetime.

For example:

```
enum TestEnum {
    Dynamic(String),
    NoValue,
    ConstStr(&'static str)
}
fn main () {
    use TestEnum::*;
    println!("NoValue:   {:?}", &NoValue as *const TestEnum);
    println!("NoValue:   {:?}", &NoValue as *const TestEnum);
    println!("ConstStr:  {:?}", &ConstStr("const-str") as *const TestEnum);
    println!("ConstStr:  {:?}", &ConstStr("const-str") as *const TestEnum);
    println!("Dynamic:   {:?}", &Dynamic(String::from("dynamic")) as *const TestEnum);
    println!("Dynamic:   {:?}", &Dynamic(String::from("dynamic")) as *const TestEnum);
}
```

outputs:

```
NoValue:   0x7ff6a92cf380
NoValue:   0x7ff6a92cf380
ConstStr:  0x7ff6a92cf3e8
ConstStr:  0x7ff6a92cf3e8
Dynamic:   0xd56df7f578
Dynamic:   0xd56df7f5f8
```

Only the `Dynamic` variant is stored in a new address on creation. You can also see this with explicit lifetimes:

```
// Compiles fine
let static_vaue : &'static TestEnum = &ConstStr("const-str"); 

// Does not compile
let dynamic_value : &'static TestEnum = &Dynamic(String::from("const-str"));
```

So the reason your code works when using `Nil` is because the `Nil` value being referenced does not get dropped after the statement as it is living in `'static` memory, so it will never be dropped.